# multiple sums on grouped tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

```
Table Header
+---------+-------+
| ref     | total | 
+---------+-------+
| 2544    |  2000 |
| 2544    |    10 |
| 2545    |  2566 |
| 2545    |    34 |
+---------+-------+

Table Items
+---------+-------+
| ref     | total | 
+---------+-------+
| 2544    |  1500 |
| 2544    |   500 |
| 2545    |  2000 |
| 2545    |   500 |
| 2545    |   100 |
+---------+-------+
```

I would like to sum the total column in both tables grouped by ref, so my output would look something like:

```
Output:
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| ref     | total_header | total_items | 
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 2544    |        2010  |       2000  |
| 2545    |        2600  |       2600  |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

I can then compare the two total columns and check for differences.

The query:

```
Select
    Header.ref,
    Sum(Header.total) as total_header
From
    Header
Group By
    Header.ref
Order By
    Header.ref Desc
```

This gives me the correct info for the Header table.  As soon as I add the Items table to the query then the total_header and total_items give the wrong values

Here is the query that I am using....

```
Select
    Header.ref,
    Sum(Header.total) as total_header,
    Sum(Items.total) as total_items
From
    Header Left Join
    Items On Header.ref = Items.ref
Group By
    Header.ref
Order By
    Header.ref Desc
```

Can anyone help me create a query that would produce the output above?  Also, if possible with another column that compares the 2 total columns giving true or false depending on if they match.

Thank you,

Martin.

Comment: You should identify the PRIMARY KEY on each table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first get the sum and then join them -

```
SELECT H.ref, H_TOT, I_TOT
FROM (SELECT ref, SUM(total) H_TOT
      FROM Header
      GROUP BY ref) H
JOIN (SELECT ref, SUM(total) I_TOT
      FROM Items
      GROUP BY ref) I ON H.ref = I.ref
ORDER BY H.ref
```

Comment: That is completely depend upon OPs intention. He may use Inner instead of LEFT.

Comment: @forpas, Updated.

Comment: Ok but as I said this will work only if each table has the same distinct refs.

Answer (score 0):

With `UNION ALL` of the 2 tables and then aggregate:

```
select t.ref,
  sum(t.total_header) total_header,
  sum(t.total_items) total_items,
  sum(t.total_header) = sum(t.total_items) matching
from (  
  select ref, total total_header, 0 total_items from Header
  union all
  select ref, 0 total_header, total total_items from Items
) t  
group by t.ref
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/65nnfDsAWYb6eYzguYSgM1/3).
Results:

```
| ref  | total_header | total_items | matching |
| ---- | ------------ | ----------- | -------- |
| 2544 | 2010         | 2000        | 0        |
| 2545 | 2600         | 2600        | 1        |
```

Comment: Thanks,  I used your solution as www.db-fiddle.com proved to be a handy tool to use while I extended the query.  Thanks

Comment: @MartinTrezise is there a reason that you unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution

```
SELECT refs.ref, sum_header.header_total, sum_items.items_total
FROM ( SELECT ref FROM header
       UNION
       SELECT ref FROM items ) refs
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ref, SUM(total) header_total
            FROM header
            GROUP BY ref ) sum_header USING (ref)
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ref, SUM(total) items_total
            FROM items
            GROUP BY ref ) sum_items USING (ref)
```

The best situation for this solution is:

1. `SELECT COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT ref)` is high, ~ (10 or more), for both tables.
2. `ref` is indexed in both tables (additionally try `SELECT DISTINCT ref FROM` in first subquery for both tables).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use

```
Select ref, sum(header.total) as total_header, sum(items.total) as total_items
from header,items where header.ref = items.ref
group by ref
order by ref desc
```

Comment: What is the difference between your query and OPs second query.

Comment: I don't understand what is the OPs query

Comment: Your query will give wrong result due to cross-join multiplying. PS. OP == original poster, the question author.

Comment: @Akina, This is not Cross Join. He is using join conditions in where clause.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai "cross-join multiplying" is an effect when the value from one join is multiplied due to more than one record from another join. It is not relative to `CROSS JOIN` joining type. I admit that I am misinterpreting this term into English.